# Unknown command: verify-app-links when using adb shell pm verify-app-links

Tags: android, adb, android-app-links

I'm using applinks follow: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations

When use cmd : `adb shell pm verify-app-links`

```
show: Unknown command: verify-app-links
```

my adb version is:

```
$ adb --version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 31.0.3-7562133
```

almost the latest, why Unknown command: verify-app-links?

Comment: have tried the platform-tools 31.0.3 
 https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools

Comment: Got it , thanks, used Android 10 device to test the cmd failed. Try it in the Android 12 succeeds. @Robert

Comment: I converted my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The prefix `adb shell` indicates that the command is executed on Android side, thus unless the `adb shell` command itself fails the platform-tools have no impact on the command.

A little bit up on the linked page you can read "Starting in Android 12". Most likely `adb shell pm verify-app-links` is also limited to devices with Android 12 or higher.

Comment: running android 12 emulator, as long the device is online/available, and don't forget to runs your apps as well with the proper package, to verify the app link, I'm able to execute this command line program now. thanks!